# after login redirect different user to their last visited url in php

Tags: php

I have a login form. I want that when a user login in its account then he gets redirected to the last page that he visited before logging out in his last signed in session.
i tried using

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION))
 {
 session_start();
  } 
  $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

in every page and in login page i used:

```
session_start();    
if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) 
$url = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
else 
 $url = "login-home.php"; // default page for 

header("Location: $url");
```

but using this every user is directed to the same page.....the page first user has last visited......but i want to direct every user to thier own last visited page...what is wrong with my code.please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you storing `$_SESSION['url']` in the database, along with other user details, just before he logs out? And when a user logs in, retrieve that URL from the database (based on user ID or username) and redirect him there. I don't see any need for using $_SESSION in this particular case.

$_SESSION isn't your answer, as it does not magically bind the user accessing the page to a registered user (that has its credentials stored in the database).

As I understand from your question, what you need is

> get redirected to the last page that he visited before logging out
>   in his last signed in session

Not to the last page he visited before he got to the login page (as all the answers here focus on), but to a previous state from the last time he was logged in. You need to remember that state in the database.

Session and user authentication are two very different things.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to add the current url to the login form. In a hidden field. When the user is logged in, use that POST or GET data to redirect the user back to it's origin.

Answer (score -1):

```
session_start();    
if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) 
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
else 
 $url = "login-home.php"; // default page for 

header("Location: $url");
```

for last page visited you need to use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: after adding this...it is not even going to login-home.php for any user ....it is refreshing the login.php page for every user..please tell why?

Comment: try: $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; and in part two of your code: $url = $_SESSION['url']; You need to respect referrer properties. referrer take last visited page, for example if you are on index and join in contact page, the referrer will be index.php Or you can store in db, at logout, last page, and redirect user to it (pt is not the best practice) Try another trick. Store referral link in session

Comment: how give -1 and why? isn't the first..and i want to understand i receive -1 .. thank you